# I need clarification for an audio power amplifier circuit component

Tags: amplifier, analog, audio, digital-audio, audio-codec

Below is the block diagram of my first design using an  [audio power](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm4670.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1685085091255&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fgeneral%252Fdocs%252Fsuppproductinfo.tsp%253FdistId%253D10%2526gotoUrl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Flm4670) amplifier.

The input to the audio power amplifier comes from an [SC200](https://www.quectel.com/product/lte-sc200e-smart-module-series) module by Quectel.

The output of the PA is connected to a [speaker](https://www.digikey.in/en/products/detail/cui-devices/CES-303206-240L40-67/12424506?s=N4IgTCBcDaICwE4AMBaAwgUQMoGYk7CQDYw4kyiB2EAXQF8g).

I have couple of questions:

1. Will the PA I selected w be able to drive this 4 ohm speaker?
2. What are the things to be considered when selecting the PA for driving a speaker?
3. How much power will I get at the output?
4. In digikey during PA selection I can see that, Max Output Power x
   Channels @ Load is "3W x 1 @ 4Ohm" May I know what you mean by this?
5. What will happen if I used the PA with above spec to 8 ohm speaker

[image]

Comment: @tobalt,Desired loudness is not used,this speakers are used in our EV(bike) to give some notifications.The SC200 can support max 3W

Comment: 4. At 5 V Vdd. 5. Assume half. Do you know how to calculate power according to Ohm's law? Do you know how to calculate the RMS value of a sine wave for a given peak voltage?

Comment: "5. What (watt?) happens with an 8 Ω speaker" It's the next entry in the datasheet from that quoted by tobalt - 680 mW minimum at 1% THD&N. The datasheet is your friend; read it thoroughly. Note the small print surrounding any parameters you wish to use. You'll need to recreate those conditions to achieve the stated parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datasheet gives pretty precise information:

[image]

If it could output the full supply voltage as Vpk, then the power would be a bit higher (closer to 2 W), but Delta Sigma PAs of modulation order higher than 2 have a maximum stable relative amplitude, which they cannot exceed for stability reasons.

Driving this 2 W speaker with 1.2 W sounds like a nice balance of loudness and headroom, and a "good" (as far as possible with such speaker) recipe for good audio reproduction.

If you want the full 3 W into 4 Ω, you will need a higher supply voltage as shown also in the datasheet Fig. 10:

[image]

Fig. 11 shows what to expect with an 8 Ω speaker. The power will be lower as expected, but most often, 8 Ω speakers can have a higher sensitivity (more loudness per power), so you must calculate loudness for each speaker and its corresponding sensitivity.

Comment: Thank you.I edited the question.Added two more questions.If you don't mind could you please check